# Use @media to target computer screen

Tags: css

I have a website. The content is set to 960px wide and devices that are wider than that see the solid colored body element. I am trying to add a background-image to that body, but I only want it to load on devices that can see the body, so that other devices don't need to waste time loading it if they can't see it.

For example, my viewport meta tag is set to a static 960px (I know it's not recommended), so phones won't be able to see the body because they are automatically scaled to 960px in width.

How can I display the background-image on only devices that are more than 960px wide, using the @media in the CSS?

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 960px) { ... }`

Comment: @Aziz Will this still download the image file, even if it doesn't display the background image?

Comment: No, https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: @Aziz That works then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I display the background-image on only devices that are more than 960px wide, using the @media in the CSS?**

**Do you mean this?**

```
body{
  background:url('http://mobilemarketingwatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Is-Google-Searching-for-the-Next-Big-Thing1.jpg');
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) { 
    body{
       background:none;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ea74ccLr/2/show/)

If you resize your browser the body background image will gone.

Comment: Actually doing this will not prevent the original image from loading on mobile devices. It should be done otherwise: load small image as default then use `min-width` query to load a larger one if the width is larger than 960px. Further reading: https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: what do you mean @Aziz ? will not prevent the original image from loading on mobile devices??????

Comment: OP wants this solution because they don't want people on mobile devices to download the full size background (because generally mobiles have slower connection and loading speed is very important). check the article I linked for more information